# Why is that div resizes with the content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a div which looks like a button with the help of the bootstrap framework. But when I increase the font size of the content inside the div, the width and height of the button changes. I just want to increase the font. But the button size should be same. 
Here is the code

```
.bigfatbutton{
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 2em;
    background: #6130a3;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
<div class="bigfatbutton">
    Review & Pay
</div>
```

Note: I just want to know onething. Some helpful persons are mentioning me to use px for padding and margin instead of em I have used in my code snippet. Is that okay? How will it effect the responsiveness is my concern. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Please refer CSS [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: don't use margin and padding in em..rather than use with px and then font size wont affect div size.

Comment: Could you show me working demo in jsfiddle or something else so that i can find out the problem easily?

Comment: you want the text to overflow the button?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/0crhd0of/1/  and you will see changing font size won't affect size of div.

Comment: You can put there markup and css for markup.Then i will take care of other things.

Comment: @gates, did you check my fiddle? you got the point?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I think I have messed up with that part. But it's recommended to use em right? Is using overflow:hidden the correct solution @Leothelion

Comment: @mahmud: That was just the code I am having. Anyway I will try to follow up with your suggestion of using fiddle from next time :)

Comment: `em` is equal to font size, and it's what you've used to define your margins and height, so when you change the font size, they'll change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining your margins and paddings relative to your fontsize. (you defined them in `em`, which is equal to the font-size.) This can easily be overcome by changing the `em` sizes to `pt` (or `px`). You'd then get something like this:

```css
.bigfatbutton{
  margin-top: 15pt;
  margin-bottom: 30pt;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 30pt;
  background: #6130a3;
  height: 60pt;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15pt;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigfatbutton">
  Review & Pay
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  .bigfatbutton{ 
    width: 80%;
    background: #6130a3;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
    <div class="bigfatbutton">
        Review & Pay
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vuyj43z/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.bigfatbutton`. Just change the `font-size` according to your requirement, button size would remain same.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0crhd0of/3/) is the working example.

I also recommend you to refer [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) so that you can make changes in your code as you want.

Comment: It does not work. In the mobiles like iphone 5 and 6, button size is changing

Comment: I did not want to represent in px. In your fiddle you have made everything as px instead of em. Help me in fixing with the use of em

Comment: I understood your problem exactly.
This might be [homework](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).
I am giving here some links to study, these would really help you.
[CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), [Responsive Web Design](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

Comment: But I did try right? And you can see what I have tried. I have a problem with knowing the responsiveness effect If I want to change it to px. And look at my edit. Thanks